# How to pass text from view to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml

Hi there i have problem with `Rails` & `Javascript`. Here is my table in view.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr id="adminrow">
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" id="select_name">John</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="adminrow">
        <td>
          2
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" id="select_name">Alex</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="adminrow">
        <td>
          3
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" id="select_name">Paul</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and my `JS` is

```
$('#select_name').click(function(event){
    var username = $("#select_name").text();
    console.log(username);
});
```

I have lot of names in my table, but `JS` printed first name in console. How can I print each name in the table to console?

Comment: what you try to solve?

Comment: in js file use this `var username = $(this).text()` hope it work

Comment: @uzaif i mean table data is in loop i want every data pass to JS. Example Name is like John, Alex, Wade, Paul... var username is like John, Alex, Wade, Paul. But now it's printed only John.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating in the each-loop N links (by the number of users) with the same `select_name` ID. Your javascript is confused, which one to choose. Try to add user id to your html `select_name` id and adjust your javascript accordingly. Same about your other id `adminrow`.

OR simply change your `select_name` to be a class and not id:

```
 ....
 %a{:href=>"#", :class=>"select_name"}=u.firstname
 ....
 $('.select_name').click(function(event){ ....
```

Ok, I am attaching the full code for you. For me it works just fine. E.g. prints just the name after clicking on the corresponding link:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="adminrow">
      <td>
        1
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="select_name">John</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="adminrow">
      <td>
        2
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="select_name">Alex</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="adminrow">
      <td>
        3
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="select_name">Paul</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.select_name').click(function(event){
    var username = $(this).text();
    console.log(username);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: How can i do this?

Comment: @NeoTeo: Adjusted the  answer.

Comment: Thanks but it's printed all data in same time. I want print each names by click on names

Comment: @NeoTeo: As @uzaif has pointed out in the comments, you should be using `var username = $(this).text()`. I thought that you have already spotted that error.

Comment: @NeoTeo: I just added the full code to the answer. Testing shows that it works just fine. Check/compare with your code again.